# How to get Context inside an Object?

Tags: android, kotlin, jwt, retrofit, token

I am using retrofit to fetch some data and for that I am passing a token in Header for Authentication.
I want to fetch the token from the Shared Preferences in my Retrofit Client Object but I don't know how to?

I tried to get a context in the object using  a function but then it gives me WARNING that

```
Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static reference to RetrofitClient which has field context pointing to Context); this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run) less...
```

Also i tried to get context in my interface of retrofit and I got the context without warning but I don't know where to get Shared Preferences.

```
interface Api {
    var context:Context;
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("getMerchantProductsSlideContent")
    fun getProductsForSlide(

 //Don't know how to get value from shared refercne to this header
        @Header("Authentication: Bearer ")

        @Field("token") token:String,
        @Field("deviceId") deviceId:String,
        @Field("content_receiver") content_receiver:String,
        @Field("content_type") content_type:String,
        @Field("data") data:Array<String>
    ):Call<DefaultResponse>

    fun getContext(mContext:Context){
        context = mContext
    }

}
```

This is retrofitClient.kt

```
object RetrofitClient {

    private val AUTH = "Bearer $token"
    private const val BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.5/Projects/Sitapuriya/public/"

    private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor { chain ->
            val original = chain.request()

            val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", AUTH)
                .method(original.method(), original.body())

            val request = requestBuilder.build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }.build()

    val instance: Api by lazy{
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()

        retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
    }
}
```

This is my retrofit interface

```
interface Api {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("getMerchantProductsSlideContent")
    fun getProductsForSlide(

        @Field("token2") token2:String,
        @Field("deviceId") deviceId:String,
        @Field("content_receiver") content_receiver:String,
        @Field("content_type") content_type:String,
        @Field("data") data:Array<String>

    ):Call<DefaultResponse>

}
```

[UPDATED] This is my activity n which i am calling the retrofit

```
  val data = arrayOf(merchantId)
                RetrofitClient.instance.getContext(this)
                RetrofitClient.instance.getProductsForSlide(
                    token,
                    deviceId,
                    "MERCHANT",
                    "MERCHANT_VIEW_BASIC",
                    data
                ).enqueue(object:Callback<DefaultResponse>{

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<DefaultResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                       Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"ERROR: ${t.message}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<DefaultResponse>,
                        response: retrofit2.Response<DefaultResponse>
                    ) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"SUCCESS: ${response.body()?.content}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }

                })
```

I want to get the token from Shared Preferences and use it as a header for my request and I know to access Shared Preferences we need a context. How can I get the context in Object?

[UPDATE-2] Tried @Blundell answer

```
interface Api {
   var token: String
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("getMerchantProductsSlideContent")

    fun getProductsForSlide(
        @Header("Authentication: Bearer $token")
        @Field("token") token:String,
        @Field("deviceId") deviceId:String,
        @Field("content_receiver") content_receiver:String,
        @Field("content_type") content_type:String,
        @Field("data") data:Array<String>
    ):Call<DefaultResponse>

    fun setAuthHeader(token2:String){
        token = token2
    }
}
```

But it gives error: *An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant*

Comment: Where is the code where you call the method `getProductsForSlide`? you can access SharePreferences there

Comment: you better use dagger2 or add an interceptor or pass header via parameters

Comment: check the project it will help you. https://github.com/zigic88/Dagger2-Retrofit

Comment: If you want to fetch data from Shared then without making major change in your code, you can simply get it by extending application class static method to get context and then create sharedpreferences object.

Comment: @Blundell Please check updated question

Comment: Ok I will try to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get token in your activity (you can use activity's context and get token from shared preferences) and pass this token to your retrofit class.

Also try to read something about dependency injection, dagger2, koin etc to provide different dependencies to your classes

```
interface Api {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("getMerchantProductsSlideContent")
    fun getProductsForSlide(
        @Header("Authentication") token:String,
        @Field("deviceId") deviceId:String,
        @Field("content_receiver") content_receiver:String,
        @Field("content_type") content_type:String,
        @Field("data") data:Array<String>
    ):Call<DefaultResponse>
}
```

In your activity:

```
val prefToken = // get it from prefences
val token = "Bearer " + prefToken
```

Comment: Yes I can get the token inside my activity but i don't no exactly how to pass it in retrofit class. I tried something to pass the token, please see my updated  question (UPDATE-2)

Comment: @PrathamVaidya try this

Comment: Thankyou your solution worked, I am using retrofit for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to store the context in a singleton, store the header you want to send. Access the context & sharedpreferences in your Activity.

Change:

```
 RetrofitClient.instance.getContext(this)
```

To something like

```
 RetrofitClient.instance.setAuthHeader(getSharedPreferences().getString("Header"))
```

Comment: Sir I tried your answer but it gave me an error. Please check my updated question (UPDATE-2)